# How can I automatically use the name of the class?

Tags: java, android

In the code below what can I write instead of Play.this so that it could automatically use the name of the class in which it is used without the need to write the name (in this case "Play")                    `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Play.this);`

Comment: Could you show a little more context as to where this appears? What does "the class" mean?

Comment: I tried use:
`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getClass().this)` but it did not work

Comment: That makes no sense... You need a `Context` variable, not a `Class`. And `getClass().this` doesn't compile

Comment: I suggest you to google about nested classes in Java. `Play.this` just allows to nested class to use the `this` reference of the enclosing object

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What is the actual problem here? 1) Nothing can be done automatically 2) The code you've show should work fine.

Comment: I have defined this AlertDialog in a Class named Play and I am using it in a method in the same class, but when I try to call this method in a different class named Player (which) inherits Play class it says com.game.Player is not an enclosing class.

Comment: @cricket_007 His problem is just misunderstanding of Java nested classes syntax...

Comment: @DenisItskovich Maybe, but a [mcve] would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other things to think before set the context (this).

First case - If you are in a class that extends a context in its base like Activity/Services, and you are **NOT** in a inner class, you can use just "this"

Second - If you are in a class that extends a context in its base like Activity/Services, and you are in a inner class, you can use (Play.this), because the "this" in this case, is about the inner class.

Third - If you are in another class that does not have a context, you can pass it in constructor or method like:

```
class Test {
   public void createBuilder(Context context) {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use `Play.this` in code being part of `Play` class. Just use `this`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

However if you want to do that from your inner class, then you need `this` will not point to `Context` subclass, so you can i.e. create member in your parent class, i.e.:

```
Context mContext;
```

initialize it in i.e. `onCreate()`:

```
mContext= this;
```

and use `mContext` from your listener's code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

Comment: If this is within `new View.OnClickListener`, then, yes, you need `Play.this`

Comment: Read again `code being part of Play class`. You talk about inner class. And that's something different

Comment: An inner class is "part of another class", IMO :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `this.getClass().getName()`. If you want just the unqualified name, use `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` instead. I know very little about Android specifically, but that's how you would do it in Java in general.